# React js single function with multiple setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Button Component (Child)**

```
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var handleToUpdate = this.props.handleToUpdate;
    return (
      <button onClick={() => handleToUpdate(this.id)}>
        {this.props.title}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Index(Parent)** 
in return

```
<Button title={title1} handleToUpdate={handleToUpdate.bind(this)} />
<Button title={title2} handleToUpdate={handleToUpdate1.bind(this)} />
<Button title={title3} />
<Button title={title4} />
```

in render

```
const title1 = "test1"
const title2 = "test2"
const title3 = "test3"
const title4 = "test4"
var handleToUpdate = this.handleToUpdate;
var handleToUpdate1 = this.handleToUpdate1;
```

function

```
  handleToUpdate() {
  this.setState({})
  }

  handleToUpdate1() {
  this.setState({})
  }

var handleToUpdate = this.handleToUpdate.bind(this);
var handleToUpdate1 = this.handleToUpdate1.bind(this);
```

---

There is no issue in my code but my way of approaching to the function is not good practice I believe.

What I am doing here is I made button component(Child) and calling it four times in the parent(index). I created `onClick` props to call function and then set state.

Is there any alternative method that I can create one function with 4 `setState` and call the state according to the button id which is clicked.

To Make it more clear.

Button 1 clicked => call singlefunction => setstate1

Button 2 clicked => cal singlefunction => setstate 2
...

Comment: You could pass the button click event to the handToUpdate function and then do switch statement to determine which button was clicked, and then you can set the corresponding state ?

Comment: @AshleyBrown is it possible can you provide me a piece of code or same example. please

Comment: Done, check out my answer.

Comment: Where do you keep the `id`?

Comment: store it on the individual buttons? i assumed you had that already set up since you pass `(this.id)`

Comment: @contactdummy Just a quick note: You could change your Button component to a stateless functional component. You don't have to to make it work, but it is better practice in this situation.

Comment: @AshleyBrown It is not able to take ID in a switch statement. Showing undefined in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
render(){
    const titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4'];

  return(
    {
     titles.map((title, i)=>(
     <Button title={title} key={i} 
             handleToUpdate={()=>this.handleToUpdate(i)} />
               ))
    }
}
```

in your `handleToUpdate` function/method, you should then use the parameter `i` to determine what is done. You could also use a parameter like `(e)=>this.handleToUpdate(e)` and then name the button with the title and access the name via `e.target` as follows:

```
handleToUpdate(e){
   const {name} = e.target;
   this.setState({[name]: true});
}
```

You can replace `true` in set state to whatever you want, however using a boolean is best if you are doing an action with a single potential result, i.e. always setting state in the same way as you presented in your question.

To pass the function with an id directly in the case of different locations for your buttons do this:

```
<Button title={title1} handleToUpdate={()=>this.handleToUpdate(1)} />
```

where `1` is an index with any number to plugin, or any key to use in a switch statement.

In your Button component change the `onClick` to:

```
<button onClick={this.props.handleToUpdate}> {this.props.title} </button>
```

You are basically binding the parameter to the function directly as in the map function I have above.

With this solution, you can just do a switch statement like in Ashley Brown's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are passing the `id` to the `Button` component, here is an alternative approach.

```js
const buttons = [
  { id: 1, title: "test1" },
  { id: 2, title: "test2" },
  { id: 3, title: "test3" },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clicked: "",
  };

  onUpdate = ( id ) => {
    this.setState( { clicked: id } );
  };

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
      <div>
        {buttons.map( button => (
          <Button
            key={button.id}
            button={button}
            onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
          />
        ) )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Button = ( props ) => {
  const { button, onUpdate } = props;
  const handleUpdate = () => onUpdate( button.id );
  return <button onClick={handleUpdate}>{button.title}</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Why would you make an object with an id? Each array member would already have an index.

Comment: Indexes are not good every time. I know probably order won't change here, so using an index would be fine but I prefer using id's if I create my own lists.

Comment: that's fair, but at that point why not just use the title directly?

Comment: If you are asking for the `key` since the code is just a fake one I can' be sure the titles are unique or not. This is barely an example :)

Comment: Ah, also if I do some operations about this item, dealing with `id`s is easier than dealing with indexes. One `filter` is enough for that. No hassle for finding indexes.

Comment: No, not the key, I meant as a parameter to `onClick`. They key should probably be the iterator + title. Those two would hardly likely to be the same lol. My only issue is adding ID explicitly seems unnecessary. Otherwise your solution looks nearly the same as what I would do.

Comment: with `filter` you would still have to be very explicit in a weird way with the id's. You would intuitively do it by title or index. An explicit id is basically a non indexed index.

Comment: Got it know :) I used `id`s for two reasons. 1. OP have an `id` in their component. 2. As I said this is a fake code, maybe there will be more in the button object, so I just used an id there. I don't know, I am still in the learning progress. Maybe this is not the best way of doing this :) Using ids is easier for me. I don't like using indexes if I don't have to. Pass the index, find the index in the array do something, etc. Instead, pass the id, use filter, do something. I like this one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch to determine which button was clicked based on the `id` you passed in... Alternatively you could have passed in the event if you hadn't have passed in the `id` already. Just be sure to set up the props if you haven't already...

```
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var handleToUpdate = this.props.handleToUpdate;
    return (
      <button onClick={() => handleToUpdate(this.id)}> // <- this id you passed in
        {this.props.title}
      </button>
    );
  }
}


<Button id={1} title={title1} handleToUpdate={handleToUpdate.bind(this)} />
<Button id={2} title={title2} handleToUpdate={handleToUpdate.bind(this)} />

handleToUpdate(id) { // <-- id passed in
  switch(id) {
   case 1: // if id === 1
    //setState({})
   break;

   case 2: // if id === 2
    //setState({})
   break;
   // etc
 } 
}
```

Comment: If the title prop is is unique you could just pass that to the `onClick` function but otherwise follow this pattern.

Comment: @Ashley Brown It is not able to take ID in a switch statement.  Showing undefined in the console.

Comment: It's probably something to do with the `this.id` I can't tell where it's coming from at a glance.

Comment: @DavidKamer I believe so but I like the approach using a switch statement. Is there any way I can get ID  value in switch statement.

Comment: @contactdummy look at my answer and pass your id to the button like I am showing. Ignore the last half of the question if you don't care about it.

Comment: @DavidKamer  It is working but I will place this buttons in four different places in the same component. For that I will need switch statement and ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181643/discussion-between-david-kamer-and-contact-dummy).

Comment: @DavidKamer can you help me this issue please  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770794/react-js-rechart-zoom-in-out-and-brush-issue)