# React.Js - rechart zoom IN/OUT and Brush issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am using [Rechart](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/AreaChartFillByValue) library and using AreaChartFillByValue. I am facing following issues 
1) When I zoom in the chart goes outside the x-axis and when I zoom out it just reset to where it started for example: suppose the current starting point is 1 to 15 but actual data is 30 and when I zoom in it shows 5 to 10 value in x-axis and when I zoom it takes back to 1 to 15 value. I want it should zoom till the entire data display from 1 to 30.
 
2) When I zoom in brush should zoom out and show the filter starting and ending point for example: suppose the current starting point is 1 to 15 and when I zoom in it shows 5 to 10 value in x-axis but the brush still shows 1 to 15 value.

3) I am not able to drag the chart when it is zoom in. I am able to drag the brush and update the chart display but not able to do it from the chart.

4) The color split is not working when I use a brush. The positive value display in green and negative value display in red. But it is not taking middle value properly. I followed the official tutorial [link](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/AreaChartFillByValue) using the brush it is giving the same issue.

I tried all the examples which are available on the internet but not able to find a solution for zoom in and brush. It would great if anyone can resolve this issue. As there no similar open issues in [GITHUB](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues)

To make it more clear please see the below two expected image. 
**My output** 
[image: Myoutput]
**My Code: [stackblitz editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-recharts-2kemus)**
**Expected output**
[image: one]

[Example Link for the above image](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172)

[image: two]

[Example Link for the above image](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/brush-zoom/)

Comment: I'm noticing that the brush is zooming so it's doing double zoom. There has to be a way to disable the brush zoom, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @DavidKamer even I tried all the possibilities

Comment: I migrated to Victory for these features.